# floating a div over an (absolutely positioned?) background div (or image)

Tags: css, html, background, absolute

I couldn't seem to find a reference to this problem anywhere after lengthy searching. This probably means I am missing basic concepts but I am going to go ahead and ask anyway.  I am trying to have a `float:left` `<div>` overlay a background image. A simplified version of the problem is below (with a div representing the image for quick reproducibility)

```
<div style='position: absolute; background-color: blue; width: 500px; height: 500px'>
     BACKGROUND DIV
</div>
<div style='float: left; background-color: yellow; width: 100px; height: 100px'>
     FLOATING IMAGE
</div>
```

It seems the absolutely positioned div overlays the float. How do I sort this out - without resorting to the `background-image` property of the parent (this is not an option) ?

Answer (score 1):

Set position:relative; on the floating element and assign a z-index:1; to the background and z-index:2; to the floating image.

```
<div style='position: absolute; background-color: blue; width: 500px; height: 500px'>
 BACKGROUND DIV
</div>

<div style='position:relative; float: left; background-color: yellow; width: 100px; height: 100px; z-index:2;'>
 FLOATING IMAGE
</div>
```

EDIT: here's a jsfiddle for your reference: http://jsfiddle.net/exUm7/1/

Comment: @TheBronx Yes z-index requires position to be set.

Comment: it seems there is no need to add z-index, as the last `div` appears over previous ones. It is the `position:relative` that solves the problem.

Comment: @TheBronx - true if the order of document elements remains as it is. z-index ensures it works whichever order the elements are in within the dom

Comment: agreed - `position: relative` on the float fixes the problem. Great! Thanks Joe & TheBronx. Looks like I need to read over the positioning documentation again...

Comment: No problem @user2143479 - could you perhaps mark my answer as the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

Div overlay is not a good idea other than if you are doing game kind of thing. I think is batter if you plan your layout as much as without overlay. It will make you easy.

but if you must need to do this. Here we go

```
<div style='float:left; background-color:blue; width:500px; height:500px; z-index:1'>
BACKGROUND DIV
</div>
<div style='float:left; margin-left:-500px; background-color:yellow; width:100px; height:100px; z-index:2'>
FLOATING IMAGE
</div>
```